# Pasar información de la base de datos a una tabla?

Tags: java, netbeans

Ya tengo la base de datos donde pasa el while y hace la ejecución de buscar datos en la columna pero ahora esa información la quiero pasar a una tabla y que la muestre en pantalla como GUI interface gráfica de usuario

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Has visitado [tour] y [ask]? ¿Qué significa "la base de datos donde pasa el while"? ¿Te refieres que tienes una base de datos sobre la que ejecutas un SELECT lanzado desde código java? ¿Qué librería estás usando para crear el GUI? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora para cargar los datos que te devuelve en una tabla?

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55635012/2553194) tienes un ejemplo de cómo cargar datos de una consulta en un JTable. Investiga qué es un JTable, cómo funciona e intenta aplicarlo a tus necesidades específicas. Si tienes un problema específico con eso, edita tu pregunta añadiendo todos los detalles. Si no hay código, poco podemos ayudarte.